# ProtocolError IncompleteRead using requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, python-requests

I got this wierd error when I tried to download some images using `requests` with quite a brief code as follows,

```
import requests
import StringIO

r = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    r.raw.decode_content = True
    data = StringIO.StringIO(r.raw.data)
    # other code to deal with data
```

then I get this error,

```
ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(15060 bytes read, 55977 more expected)', IncompleteRead(15060 bytes read, 55977 more expected))
```

I googled similar problems, and try to force requests using HTTP/1.0 protocol like this,

```
import httplib
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
httplib.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'
```

however, the server simply returns me an `403` status code.

By the way, what's more confusing is the `ProtocolError` does not happens every time but sometimes.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The server closed the connection before it sent the content-length, can you share a reproducible example?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error by any specific example, it happens all irregular.  @ Padraic Cunningham

Comment: But is it to a specific domain?

Comment: Well, it's true. I analyze the log and find that all it happens when I try to fetch images from the same domain.  @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `stream=True` you should iterate over the response and save the file in chunks:

```
with open('pic1.jpg', 'wb') as handle:
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)

    if response.ok:
        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break
            handle.write(block)
```

Note that this will save an actual file, but can be modified to use `StringIO`:

```
with StringIO() as handle:
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)

    if response.ok:
        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break
            handle.write(str(block))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! actually I used to think about this, but as I mentioned above what get me more confused, is not all requests appears this problem. If I used the wrong method, why this difference?

Comment: @streethacker Not sure, I suppose that if the response size is small enough then it can be read in one go, hence no `IncompleteRead` will be raised.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not the key point, cause I analyze the log file again and found an image more than 102KB(100666 bytes) has been successfully downloaded, while the error message I posted above shows the problem image is only 71KB(71037 bytes, 15060 + 55977) . Anyway, really appreciated for your answer and I'll try it first.

Comment: @ DeepSpace I tried your suggestion, and tracked the log for more than 10 days, its completely fixed the ProtocalError, really grateful for your answer!